# ¿Se puede obligar a una clase Java a implementar una propiedad determinada?

Tags: java

¿Hay alguna forma de obligar a una clase a que implemente una propiedad de un determinado tipo?

Por ejemplo, tengo las clases `Xxx` y `Zzz`, y quiero que ambas estén obligadas a implementar la propiedad `name` de tipo *String*.

> **Editado**

Lo que quiero esque Xxx y Zzz (y cualquier otra clase que se cree posteriormente en el paquete), tengan la siguiente estructura:

```
package xxx.tests;

public class Foo {

    private final static String NAME;

    static {
        NAME = "mi name";
    };


    public static String get(String name) {

        if (name.equals("")) {
            return name;
        }

        return NAME;
    }

} // class
```

Es decir que todas estas clases tengan una propiedad de un tipo concreto que deben inicializar y el método con un argumento y tipo de retorno definidos. Para el método implementó una interfaz.

Answer (score 1):

Las propiedades no se implementan(interface), se extienden(extends).

```
public class Padre {
    protected String name;
}
public class Xxx extends Padre {
    public Xxx() {      
    }
}
public class Zzz extends Padre {
    public Zzz() {  
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Xxx x=new Xxx();
        Zzz z=new Zzz();
        x.name="algoX";//Heredo la propiedad name
        z.name="algoZ";//Heredo la propiedad name
    }
}
```

En cambio con interfaces:

```
public interface IPadre {
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
}
public class Xxx implements IPadre {
    private String name;//Esto podria no existir en esta clase
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;//Esto podria no existir en esta clase
    }
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;//Esto podria no existir en esta clase
    }
}
public class Zzz implements IPadre {
    private String name;//Esto podria no existir en esta clase
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;//Esto podria no existir en esta clase
    }
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;//Esto podria no existir en esta clase
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Xxx x=new Xxx();
        Zzz z=new Zzz();
        x.setName("algoX");
        z.setName("algoZ");
        System.out.println(x.getName());
        System.out.println(z.getName());
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver con `extends`, **una propiedad se hereda**. Y con `implements` un **método se implementa**.

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que mas te ayudo haciendo clic en la palomita

Answer (score 0):

podes crear una clase abstracta que tenga como atributo "name" de tipo String y que se llame ClasePadre o algo asi, y que las clases xxx y zzz herenden de esta mediante extends, todas las subclases de ClasePadre heredan los atributos y metodos. no se si es conveniente usar atributos en las interfaces , creo que puede generar errores corrijanme si me equivoco